# Integral around singularity proportional to angle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

For a contour integral in a closed path we have the Residue Theorem:

$$ \int_\gamma f(z) dz = 2\pi i \sum_k Res(f, z_k) $$

If $\gamma$ is not closed, but, for example, is defined as $ \gamma(\theta) = Re^{i \theta}$, $\theta \in [0, \pi]$. Do we have 
$$ \int_\gamma f(z) dz = \pi i \sum_k Res(f, z_k) ?$$

For some context: when evaluating a real integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, with a singularity at $z=0$, we can use a path that excludes this singularity from the interior of the curve, however we still have its contribution in the integral.

Comment: If the path is not closed  how do you know which singularities are inside? In the case you describe in the "context" what you want is true when the little semicircle round $0$ tends to $0$, provided the singularity is a simple pole.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the case. Why do we have this result when the semicircle tends to zero?

Comment: I think all the books will give you a proof. I used to use E T Copson or H A Priestley. The argument is not difficult,straightforward estimate of the difference between the integral and the share of the residue.